# How to shift an array to left or right in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have an array `a[]={1,0,0,0,0};` and I want to rotate it so it ends up like this: `a[] = {0,0,0,0,1};`

how can I shift one element to the left or more then one?

```
#include<iostream.h>

int main ()
{                      
     int temp,a[] = {1,0,0,0,0};              
     for(int i =0;i<=4;i++)
     {
        temp = a[0];
        a[i] = a[i-1];
        a[4] = temp;  
        cout << a[i];
     }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i wonder it there might be a [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) or something.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf probably yes. Vlad got it ...

Comment: @cubuspl42 Of course we can! See e.g. Vlad's answer

Comment: As you can see, from the answers below, there are library routines that can do it. However I urge you to try for your self (for practice), then use the library. Consider what needs to be in the loop, and what direction the data is going( in you code some is going one way and some the other). Also don't print in the loop, do it before and after.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use standard algorithm `std::rotate` declared in header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    std::rotate( std::begin( a ), std::next( std::begin( a ) ), std::end( a ) );

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0 0 0 0 1
```

Statement

```
    std::rotate( std::begin( a ), std::next( std::begin( a ) ), std::end( a ) );
```

can be written simpler

```
    std::rotate( a, a + 1, a + 5 );
```

ALso you can use standard algorithm `std::rotate_copy` if you want to have the original array unchanged.

If you compiler does not support the range-based for loop then you can write

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
```

Comment: @user3527076 See the reason in your code. It seems you typed it with errors.

Comment: @user3527076 Also if the error occured in the range-based for statement then substitute it for an ordinary loop. If you are using the MS VC++ 2010 then you can substitute it for for each ( int x in a ) std::cout << x << ' ';

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to C++11, this can be done by creating an [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) and then using it's [`cshift` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/cshift) (which stands for circular-shift).

An [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) is an object that was designed, as a part of the [C++ 2011 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), to hold an array of values, and then easily perform operations on them, such as mathematical operators and common functions like [`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/swap) or [`shift`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/shift).

As an example:

```
#include <valarray>

int main()
{
  int myInts[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

  std::valarray<int> myValArray(myInts, 5);  // 1 2 3 4 5
  myValArray = myValArray.cshift(2);         // 3 4 5 1 2 - rotated left
  myValArray = myValArray.cshift(-1);        // 2 3 4 5 1 - rotated right

  return 0;
}
```